# WooCommerce - How to get customer's city from review/comment?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a plugin that will cycle through all customer reviews and show them on any page.

I know how to get the user's display name from the review/comment, but how to get his billing location also?

I think what I need is a way to get the WooCommerce user data from the review/comment ID - if this is possible??

Answer (score 1):

Providing they've submitted an order and you've got their user ID, you should be able to do something like:

```
$city = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', true );
```

or...

```
$city = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', true );
```

It might be worth having a look at your user meta table to see what's in there.

**Edit**

Just re-read the question and maybe you don't have the user ID yet. You should be able to get this from the `$wpdb->comments` table.

Comment: That should still work. If querying and looping through the comments, you should be able to get the comment author ID.

Comment: Is the a WordPress function to get the comment's author ID from the API? (The only one I could find that looked like it may do the job was deprecated.)

Comment: Have you tried [get_comment_author()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_author) ?